# Laravel's route doesn't see controller's action

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to learn Laravel, and I created controller (using artisan's `php artisan controller:make AlbumController`). Then, I added some functions there, mainly function `parse`:

```
/**
 * Parse the album.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function parse($id)
{
    return 'http://api.deezer.com/'.$id;
}
```

In `routes.php` I added

```
Route::resource('album', 'AlbumController');
```

But when I try to access the `parse` page (`http://localhost/album/parse/123`) Laravel returns `throw new NotFoundHttpException();`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`parse` is not an included route in Laravel's resourse controller. Run `php artisan routes` to see your current route structure.

If you want to use the `parse` method in your controller you should define the route manually. Add something like

```
Route::get('album/parse/{id}', ['uses' => 'AlbumController@parse']);
```

to your routes file.

As an aside, the resource controller can be a handy way to get your CRUD routes up and running but it is good practice to define most of your routes explicitly as your `routes.php` file is useful documentation for your application and it makes the workings of it much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the route to

```
Route::get('album/parse/{id}', 'AlbumController@parse');
```

More of routing with parameters can you find [HERE](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) inside the Laravel Docs

And the docs with some information about [Routing with Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)

An little part of my route to give you an idea of how it could look:

```
Route::get('/partijen/nieuw', 'PartijenController@nieuw');
Route::post('/partijen/nieuw', 'PartijenController@save_new');
Route::get('/partijen/edit/{id}', 'PartijenController@edit');
Route::post('/partijen/edit/{id}', 'PartijenController@save_edit');
```